# $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable vs. $\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ a measurable space and $f \colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ a function. Is it right, that $f$ is $\mathcal{E}$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable iff $i \circ f$ is $\mathcal{E}$-$\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable, where $i$ is the inclusion $\mathbb{R} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$? ($\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) $ is the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra)

Comment: Yes, that is true. If, follows from noting that for any $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\subset 
 \mathcal{B} (\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ it holds that $(i \circ f)^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{E}$ but it also holds that $i^{-1}(A)=A$, so $f^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{E}$.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

If $f$ is $\mathcal{E}$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable, then, for all $E \in  \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$,
$$ (i \circ f)^{-1}(E) =f^{-1}(i^{-1}(E))= f^{-1}(E \cap \Bbb R) \in \mathcal{E}$$
(because $E \cap \Bbb R \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$). So, $i \circ f$ is $\mathcal{E}$-$\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable

If $i \circ f$ is $\mathcal{E}$-$\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable, then, for all $A \in  \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we have that $A \in  \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ and $i^{-1}(A) =A$. So
$$ f^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(i^{-1}(A))= (i \circ f)^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{E}$$
So, $f$ is $\mathcal{E}$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable